# Square brackets inside the name of column in VBA query?

Tags: sql, vba, database, ado

I have an issue with square brackets inside the name of column I am trying to access. 
name of column: *[KPI] Standard Delivery Capability SO [<0/0]*
this is my code:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim WhatToSelect as String

query = "Select " & WhatToSelect & " From" & sourceSheet & ".[Sheet1$]"
         rs.Open query, connection
         rs.MoveFirst
         i = rs.Fields(rs.Fields(0).name).Value
```

basicly I am trying to find variable, which would be in "WhatToSelect" variable 
 
I have tried:

```
WhatToSelect = "avg([[KPI] Standard Delivery Capability SO [<0/0]])"
WhatToSelect  =  "avg(`[KPI] Standard Delivery Capability SO [<0/0]`)"
```

nothing has worked so far. 
(it works with every other column, with no [ ] in)

Comment: Your `where` clause is not finished. What is the `where` condition?

Comment: My bad, the where part didint matter, it worked just fine, It was filled with variables so I thought the code would be more clear this way. The only issue is with the suqare brackets in column name.

Comment: Have you tried to make the column be like "[a name with \[ and \] brackets]"? So putting square brackets around the field name and escaping the square brackets already in the field?

Comment: @Roemer I am not sure, what do you mean. Could you please show me an example, how it would look on this case? In case you meant that I should change the name of column, I can't do that.

Comment: Ah, I now see that stackoverflow removed my backslashes! Arggg... Let's try again: `[a name with \[ and \] brackets]`.  But FunThomas may have a better idea.

Comment: Using backslashes as escape characters didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coudn't find any documentation about that, so I did some experiments. I created a small table containing one column with exact your column name, executed a `Select * from [Sheet1$]` and had a look to the column name within the returned recordset. Turned out that the brackets where replaced by parenthesis:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim connString As String
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""
conn.Open connString
Set rs = conn.Execute("Select * from [Sheet1$]")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name
Next

>> (KPI) Standard Delivery Capability SO (<0/0)
```

To query this field, you need to (a) enclose the field name with brackets and (b) replace the brackets within the field name with parenthesis:

```
dim fieldname as String, sql as String
fieldName = "[(KPI) Standard Delivery Capability SO (<0/0)]"

' Use field in result set:
sql = "Select " & fieldname & " from [Sheet1$]"
Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

' Use field in Where-Clause:
sql = "Select * from [Sheet1$] where " & fieldname & " > 100"
Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)
```

In your case, where you want to execute a aggregate function on that field, you need to specify

```
WhatToSelect = "avg([(KPI) Standard Delivery Capability SO (<0/0)])"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you just saved me. Was working on this single line of code for several hours.